# How to set default for a vector in a method

Tags: c++

I'm having a scenario where I need to add a vector as an input/output [reference]parameter to  existing legacy code. And in order to avoid any errors, I need to make it a default parameter.

Could someone please suggest how to add a vector as a default parameter to a method. I'm actually dubious if this is possible. Also, if this is possible, with what vallue should the vector be intialized with?

Comment: You might need to rethink your design. If the input/output reference is optional, either make a new function, or just return in from the function instead of passing it as an argument.

Comment: The problem is not `vector`; the problem is providing a default value for a reference parameter. You'd have the same issue with an `int&`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest overloading the method:

```
void foo(double otherParameter);
void foo(double otherParameter, std::vector<int>& vector);

inline void foo(double otherParameter)
{
    std::vector<int> dummy;
    foo(otherParameter, dummy);
}
```

---

An alternative design, which explicitly says that `vector` is an option in/out parameter, is:

```
void foo(double parameter, std::vector<int>* vector = 0);
```

Yes, a raw pointer -- we're not taking ownership of it, so smart pointers are not really needed.

Comment: This smells. Your answer is good, but passing the `dummy` vector to forget it afterwards points how smelly OP's design is.

Comment: @Alexandre C. There is no pleasing some people :P

Comment: yes. Overloading resolves my issue. One thing I would like to get clarified is that this orignal method is a virtual method. so, should the new overloaded method be virtual too?

Correct me, if Im wrong, but I dont think that it need to be right?

Comment: Since it calls the other virtual method, it doesn't have to be.

Comment: @quant_dev

Actually, void foo(double otherParameter); is a viratual method. And now, we are calling an overloaded method in this original virtual method.

Comment: I figured out the answer:NO:)

Thanks to all for helping me out:)

Comment: Ow! A horrible situation here. I do not think I can over ride it. The thing is the current last parameter is a default parameter. So, this new parameter,dummy, should also be the same. Now, im back 2 square one. :(

Comment: void foo(param1,param2, param3=some default value);
This is the method. Now, I need to add a default argument to it which retunrs a vector of stirngs.
Since, the third argument is a default paramenter, I m unable to overload it. And this is a legacy method and its design can't be changed.

Comment: So if I understand your problem correctly, you want to be able to call it as foo(param1), foo(param1, param3) or foo(param1, param2, param3)? Just add 2 overloads then.

Comment: :(:(:. There are situations where in the 3rd paramenter(default parameter) is set as well. And in those cases, too, this need to work.
But, if that is the case, we shall end up at the same scenario rihgt...

Comment: I still have the same issue, trying with the pointer to vector too. Basically, it wont be enough to have a simple pointer to a vector as an argument. It needs to be reference to the pointer of vector. But if that is the case, I shall end up at the same scenario:(.

Comment: Why do you think it has to be a reference to a pointer to a vector?

Comment: hi quant_dev, I gave it a try and it did not work.

Basically, I tried with this:
`code`

method1
std::vector<int>* ptr;
method2( ptr );
//now ptr does not have anything populated.

and 

method2( std::vector<int>  *ptr )
{
    ptr->pushback( integerValue );
}

Pls suggest.

Comment: You need to initialize ptr first!

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that, because a mutable lvalue reference will not bind to an rvalue. Either you use `const` and give up the out part of the param, so you can assign it a default value, or you use a mutable lvalue reference and force the caller to pass something in.

Edit: Or you can write an overload- I hadn't considered that. It's not doable in a single signature, at least.

Comment: @DeadMG
If I use a const for the default parameter, then it means that if I chose, to use it, I cannot modify it futher right?

Answer (score 1):

You can add another overload for the legacy calls.

```
void f(int param)
{
    std::vector<type> dummy;

    f(param, dummy);   // call the modified function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the default parameter has to be non-const reference type then you can do this:

```
//original function
void f(std::vector<int> & v) //non-const reference
{
      //...
}

//just add this overload!
void f()
{
     std::vector<int> default_parameter;
     //fill the default_parameter
     f(default_parameter);
}
```

If the default parameter hasn't to be non-const reference then you can do this:

```
void f(std::vector<int> v = std::vector<int>()); //non-reference
void f(const std::vector<int> & v = std::vector<int>()); //const reference
```

Comment: @DeadMG: Ohh... I didn't see that. See the answer now.

Comment: I'm still going to leave my downvote in place. A static default parameter? Just why? You're throwing thread safety out the window for nothing, not to mention that not re-creating the vector might have nasty side effects, such as a memory leak and an incredible waste of performance resizing it.

Comment: @DeadMG: I think the idea has been conveyed. Whether that local variable should be `static` or not, whether there are more than one thread or not, is not the actual point, it is upto the OP, as I don't have any knowledge of threading here. Also, non-static local variable is better for single-threaded application also?

Comment: Incomplete code is one thing. Bad code is another. This code is bad and slow in a single-thread and actively crash-my-application wrong in a multi-threaded one. This isn't the first time I've downvoted you for using static variables in completely the wrong places, and that's because they should never, ever, be used except where absolutely called for. This situation does not call for it, in any way whatsoever, and using one is wrong.

Comment: @DeadMG: Why is this bad and slow in single-thread? and how would it become fast and better if I make the local variable non-static?

Comment: It's bad and slow because when he puts stuff in the vector, it's going to stay there forever, and he's going to leak that memory and have to pay to copy around the contents and resize the buffers for absolutely no benefit or reason. It's bad because static variables are almost impossible to get rid of and a sign of incredibly poor design. It would be faster and better if you made the variable local because the memory would be freed instead of accumulating and he wouldn't be wasting time constantly copying around old results to resize the buffer.

Comment: Also note that static variables passed to other functions potentially yield concurrent (or better: uncontrollable) access in recursive situations, making non-container-modifying loops like `for (iter it=vec.begin(), end=vec.end(); ...)` potentially dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pointer:

```
void foo(legacy_parameters, std::vector<int>* pv = 0);
```

Comment: @rubenvb: I wouldn't do this in the first place. I'd make a new method `foo_ex` or `foo2` with the extra argument, and pragma-deprecate the other. But since the OP wants pass by reference semantics, the pointer is something clean, since you can test if the caller doesn't want to provide the argument.

Answer (score -4):

I think it would be like this but it is ugly.

```
void SomeFunc(int oldParams,const vector<int>& v = vector<int>())
{
vector<int>& vp = const_cast<vector<int>& >(v);
..
..
}
```

Comment: yes. But in this particular case, there isn't anyother way other than to write another wrapper function. 
Maybe putting a comment that this `const` will be be casted away will make it better.

Comment: Actually, because `const_cast` exists, the compiler can't make that assumption unless it can prove there are no casts, which is difficult.